# Difference in the result of echo and printf

Tags: shell-script, echo, printf, bc

Why do I see a difference in the results for the following code:

```
read a
printf "%.3f\n" $(bc -l <<< "$a")
```

**RESULT: 17.929**
and

```
read a
echo "scale=3; $a" | bc -l
```

**RESULT: 17.928**

My input expression is **5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7**.

They seem to be doing the same thing, but the end result is different. Why?

What change(making use of *echo*) can I make in the second snippet above to get the same result as the first snippet?

Comment: Looks like rounding differences between printf and bc. If bc is doing truncation, you could try adding 0.0005 to the result to get round-to-nearest behavior

Comment: Well the exact result is `17.9285...` so basically one solution is just dropping everything after the 8 resulting in `17.928` while the other solution uses rounding rules, which results in `17.929`.

Comment: Is there any change I can make in the echo statement, to have the rounding rules applied to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a difference between `echo` and `printf` but a difference between the number handling of `printf` and `bc`.

I guess that `printf` rounds up the last digit and that `bc` does not but just puts out the digits as calculated.

You may check this by having both approaches output more digits.

Comment: Far as I can see, "scale" truncates (does not round), and it does this on all intermediate results, not just the final output. So representational errors are going to compound very quickly. bc builds on dc, which also behaves like this.